# Scientifically Proven Positive habits hacks

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I was wondering if there are scientific proven techniques that help in making long term changes to a person's habit. Self management and motivation.

Comment: I am not an expert but I would look into Positive Reinforcement techniques. See this book as an example: http://www.amazon.com/Other-Peoples-Habits-Positive-Reinforcement/dp/007135915X     You can read the first 200 pages free on Amazon